# EB CLI installing with Python 2 rather than Python 3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

My system as Python 2.7 and 3.7 installed. I have attempted to install the EB CLI connected to Python 3 but the CLI tool seems only to connect to the 2.7 installation.

**Attempt 1**

When I run `$ brew install awsebcli` I get a version of EB that seems to be associated with 2.7, which is incorrect:

$ eb --version
EB CLI 3.14.4 (Python 2.7.1)

**Attempt 2**

When I attempt to install EB CLI using pip, the installation appears fine but I am unable to access EB.

`$eb --version
-bash: eb: command not found`

The docs suggest this might be to do with not having the path in the .bash_profile I've set up, however I have added the following to my .bash_profile and reloaded the .bash_profile:

`# Adding path to Elastic Beanstalk CLI
export Path=/Library/Python/3.7/bin:$PATH`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other way to use it is to install awsebcli in virtualenv with python 3.7.

if you dont have virtualenv install it first.

```
pip install virtualenv
```

then make virtualenv with python 3.7

```
virtualenv -p python3.7 <name of virtualenv>
```

activate this virtualenv

```
cd <name of virtualenv>
source bin/activate
```

Now install awsebcli,

```
pip install awsebcli
```

This virtualenv will now have python3.7 as default python version.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by setting the PATH variable correctly - however the solution above is better (fitting with 12Factor App design)